# How to add Perspective Bar Switcher to pure eclipse 4 rcp application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have created a pure Eclipse e4 rich client platform application application model. I created multiple perspectives using perspective stack, but I am unable to switch other perspective because there is no default perspective bar or switcher icon present in Eclipse e4. How to implement a perspective switcher in pure Eclipse e4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`EPartService.switchPerspective` will do the actual switch, but you will have to design and implement the UI.

You could use a `ToolBar` in the window Trim Bar with buttons for each perspective. Alternatively a Combo as a Tool Control with a list of the perspectives, it is up to you.

To put a control at the right of a Trim Bar you need to add two Tool Control objects to the trim. Something like:

[image: Trim layout]

The first Tool Control is just a spacer to fill the center of the bar.

On the tags tab for the control add the word `stretch` to tell e4 to stretch this control over as much space as possible:

[image: Stretch tag]

You will also have to specify a class for the control. This just needs to create an empty `Composite` to occupy the space. For example:

```java
public class SpacerControl
{
  @PostConstruct
  public void postConstruct(final Composite parent)
  {
    Composite body = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);

    body.setLayout(new FillLayout());
  }
}
```

The second Tool Control will contain your Combo control for the perspective switch. Something like:

```java
public class ComboControl
{
  @PostConstruct
  public void createGui(final Composite parent)
  {
    Combo combo = new Combo(parent, SWT.READ_ONLY);

    ... initialize Combo, add listeners, ....
  }
}
```

This should end up looking something like this:

[image: Resulting App]

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer.can you please suggest me how to add a combo at top right corner in eclipse 4? is it achievable?

Comment: Implemented the above and works fine.My Doubt is Even Perspective Switcher has to be created by the rcp developer,then How eclipse 4 rcp is better than eclipse 3 rcp?

Comment: 'Which is better' is far too broad for a comment (or Stack Overflow question). As far as the Perspective Switcher goes - in e4 you can design it any way you like, in 3.x you pretty much have to use what Eclipse gives you.