# Align logo right in Eclipse RCP coolbar

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

We are trying to implement an Eclipse RCP application with a branded logo in the top right. How can we place this in Eclipse RCP 4 on the right of the toolbar/coolbar?

We have tried putting it in the application.e4xmi file but without any success. Also coding in the Eclipse RCP is not that easy. How can we hook into the source of the Eclipse framework to do some special stuff?

Comment: Is this an e4 RCP (so your are writing your own Application.e4xmi) or is it a 3.x compatibility RCP (so it would be using the LegacyIDE.e4xmi)? The last part of your question about framework is far too broad. Ask questions about specific things that you want to do.

Comment: It's an e4 RCP application. And is it possible to skip the appliction.e4xmi and code it yourself?

Comment: Well you could mess around adding elements to the model programmatically but that is much harder than adding a tool control to the tool bar.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35063906/2670892) which describes how to put a control at the right of the trim bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Greg-449 I have found a sollution. The tutorial on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35063724/how-to-add-perspective-bar-switcher-to-pure-eclipse-4-rcp-application/35063906#35063906) did the trick.