# Perspectiveswitcher doesn't create the command object to switch the perspective

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

The problem is that the command object in my code is null and i don't know why.

I use the [e4-perspective-switcher](https://github.com/vogellacompany/e4-perspective-switcher) from Lars Vogel together with the question from here [How to add Perspective Bar Switcher to pure eclipse 4 rcp application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35063724/how-to-add-perspective-bar-switcher-to-pure-eclipse-4-rcp-application).

```java
public class PerspectiveSwitcher {

    @Inject
    private ECommandService commandService;

    @Inject
    private EHandlerService handlerService;


    @PostConstruct
    public void createControls(Composite parent, EModelService modelService) {
        Composite body = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        body.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        body.setBackground(parent.getBackground());

        Button button = new Button(body, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setText("switch");
        GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false);
        data.minimumHeight = 20;
        button.setLayoutData(data);
        button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                List<MPerspective> perspectives = modelService.findElements(app,
                        PTApplicationConstants.PERSPECTIVE_ID_MANAGER, MPerspective.class, null);
                MPerspective perspective = perspectives.get(0);

                HashMap<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>(2);
                parameters.put(E4WorkbenchParameterConstants.COMMAND_PERSPECTIVE_ID, perspective.getElementId());
                parameters.put(E4WorkbenchParameterConstants.COMMAND_PERSPECTIVE_NEW_WINDOW, "false");

                ParameterizedCommand command = commandService
                        .createCommand(E4WorkbenchCommandConstants.PERSPECTIVES_SHOW_PERSPECTIVE, parameters);
                handlerService.executeHandler(command);

                partService.switchPerspective(perspective);

                super.widgetSelected(e);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about the `command` variable? Have you declared the command in the Application.e4xmi (or fragment.e4xmi)?

Comment: i create a command with the id from the "createCommand" method in the Application.e4xmi but the command variable is still null.
```<commands xmi:id="_m2zr4E7YEemD75w3RJXENA" elementId="org.eclipse.e4.ui.perspectives.showPerspective" commandName="PerspectiveSwitcher"/>```

Comment: Did you specify `-clearPersistedState` when running the code to make sure the changes in the Application.e4xmi where picked up?

Comment: Yes i have this argument in my run configuration.

Comment: I still get this null pointer for the command.
What can be the reason that the command service cannot create this command?
Are there certain conditions that have to be given to create a command with the command service?

Comment: As far as I can see the command service **never** returns null from createCommand even when the command id is nonsense. So do some debugging and find out exactly what is null.